# Fill form data in an external iframe from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have a chrome extension that can autofill form inputs. The issue I am facing is the `iframe` is loaded from a different source. So, Chrome restricts the script that I inject into the page from accessing the iframe. There are lots of questions about this issue on SO already.

Recently I've found that the [extension by privacy.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pay-by-privacycom/hmgpakheknboplhmlicfkkgjipfabmhp) can insert an HTML element into the same `iframe` without any issues. How is this being achieved?

To reproduce,

1. Install [Pay by Privacy.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pay-by-privacycom/hmgpakheknboplhmlicfkkgjipfabmhp) Chrome extension.
2. Go to [this codepen](https://codepen.io/braintree/pen/mPgdPN) with a form
3. You'll see a "P" icon on the Credit Card number input. This is injected by the extension **inside** the iframe.
4. Try to manually select the HTML element of the Credit Card number input from the Chrome dev console. Here is the code to run, (Make sure `top` is set as the JS context in the console)

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.querySelector('#credit-card-number');
```

This will error with the following message

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://codepen.io" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:53
```

The error is expected, which I also see when trying to do the same from my extension. So, what technique is **Pay by Privacy.com** using to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use all_frames option in chrome extension's manifest.json.

You script will run directly inside every iframe.

I emailed @Jahir, and he told me this answer.
then wrote down here to help other people from wasting hours searching to get this simple answer.