# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 Fill Form Data In An External iFrame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, content-script

I am creating a chrome extension that autofills forms on a webpage. Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811662/fill-form-data-in-an-external-iframe-from-chrome-extension) I am running into the following error:

```
Error handling response: Error: Blocked a frame with origin "<URL_OF_WEBSITE>" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at chrome-extension://lmhbdbgimlffldbbijpmbinppkeopclf/content.js:56:45
```

I have tried the suggested answer of using `"all_frames": true` as well as `"match_origin_as_fallback": true` but I still receive the same error message.

Any ideas of what may be going on would be appreciated as I know there are plenty of extensions that do perform these steps perfectly.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Extension Autofill",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "ext/popup.html",
    "default_title": "Extension Autofill"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "match_origin_as_fallback": true,
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "declarativeContent"]
}
```

**content.js** - Attempt 1

```
let ifr = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[1];

if(ifr){
  ifr.contentWindow.document.getElementById('name').value = "John Doe";         
}
```

**content.js** - Attempt 2

```
function imitateKeyInput(el, keyChar) {
  const keyboardEventInit = {
    bubbles:false,
    cancelable:false,
    composed:false,
    key:'',
    code:'',
    location:0
  };
  let keyDownEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", keyboardEventInit);
  el.dispatchEvent(keyDownEvent);
  el.value = keyChar;
  let keyUpEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keyup", keyboardEventInit);
  el.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);
  let inputChangeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
  el.dispatchEvent(inputChangeEvent);
}

const el = document.querySelector('#name');
if(el) {
  el.focus();
  imitateKeyInput(el, 'John Doe');
} else {
    console.log("element NOT FOUND);
}
```

**Javascript Context**

Content script verified to be in target iFrame.

[image: Content script verified to be in target iFrame]

Tested on: Edge Version 109.0.1518.70 & Chrome Version 109.0.5414.120

Comment: Sounds like you're still trying `iframe.contentWindow` or `iframe.contentDocument`, but you should simply use `document` when the content script runs inside the iframe.

Comment: Updated with what I currently have. So how should I access the #document inside the iframe?

Comment: Just use it directly: if (window!==top) { let el = document.getElementById('name'); if (el) el.value = 'foo'; }

Comment: I replaced what I had in content.js with the above code in your comment and the field still doesn't get populated. Is it because it is looking at the main #document body and not the #document body found in the iframe?

Comment: The script runs both in the main document and inside the iframe. This is what all_frames does. Note that setting `value` is not enough on many sites, see [Enter data into a custom-handled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900849).

Comment: I appreciate your continuous help @wOxxOm I have tried using the dispatchEvent route as explained in the link you provided but I am still not able to get past the finding of the element inside the iframe. It should have been that all_frames would have done the trick but it's not able to find the element. Does my manifest.json look correct? Maybe v3 changed something that used to work on v2?

Comment: The element may be added dynamically later. You can wait for it using setTimeout or MutationObserver.

Comment: Tried setTimeout for long waiting periods and would receive a null from the querySelector. Did the MutationObserver and still won't find it either. I'm really wondering if I switch over to v2 if it would behave the same. I might have to try it because I can't get this to work.

Comment: Well, I'm out of guesses. Anyway, the approach is correct, so you should simply debug the code. Start by verifying that the content script actually runs in this iframe e.g. by adding `if (window!==top && location.href == 'your-frame-url') console.log(document)`

Comment: I truly appreciate your help with this @wOxxOm! I agree the approach is correct. I did try the window !== top and was getting false as a return but then I thought maybe top was supposed to be in quotes so I did that change and that resulted to true. Either way still getting a null return for the element. Maybe I'm missing something that I am not seeing. A website that has this exact iframe situation is Jachs NY specifically the step where you fill in the credit card info.

Comment: `top` doesn't need any quotes. Since `window!==top` is false it means your content script doesn't run in the iframe. It looks like a bug in the browser when the iframe is using srcdoc + sandbox.

Comment: So weird because I have an 2 extensions that run fine in both browsers I tested that achieve this. Thanks again for all your suggestions @wOxxOm!

Comment: Do you see those other extensions in devtools [context selector for this iframe](https://puu.sh/JybFf/86e5e5c025.png)? Anyway, debug it in devtools, there should be no need for guesswork.

Comment: I do see the extension as well as my own in the same places except in the dialog & autocomplete_service sections. If I select the javascript context to either the other extension or my extension if I do `document.querySelector('form #number')` within the specified iframe section I can set the value just fine. So through the console I can fill just fine but I can't do it programmatically?

Comment: I can't say without seeing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) or debugging it myself. Like I said, start by establishing that the content script runs in that iframe. If you see your extension in the context selector it means the content script runs there. Next try running a simple thing like console.log(location.href) and make it work. If it doesn't, but the other extensions work, then it's obviously a bug in Chrome e.g. maybe those extensions are MV2 but yours is MV3.

Comment: location.href != iframe src so I can see that's why I'm getting cors error. If I set window.location.href to the iframe's src it will redirect automatically as expected. So yeah my script is running inside the iframe but still can't populate. I'll keep trying to see what the next move should be.